# If I switch my serverside c# programs to use gcServer would you expect everything to be fine?

Tags: c#, .net

... or should I do some extensive testing.

So is it safe to simple add the config below and expect everything to behave fine with no issues?

My program are highly multi-threaded.

```
<runtime>
  <gcServer enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read about memory usage going through the roof after using it. So i would advise you to test. Better safe than sorry.